# Redirect After Delete User in Backend

Tags: redirect, user-roles, customization

How do I **redirect** to a certain page **after user deletion**?

For demonstration purpose, let's say I want to **redirect to the dashboard on user subscriber deletion**. This is what I have tried so far:

```
function mod_redirect_subscriber_delete($user_id) {
  $user  = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
  $role   = $user->roles[0];
  if ($role == 'subscriber') {
    wp_redirect( admin_url('/index.php') );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action("delete_user", "mod_redirect_subscriber_delete");
```

The above code successfully redirected me to the dashboard, but the **user didn't get deleted**.

I had also tried `deleted_user`. This deleted the user but it didn't redirect.

Any ideas?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do this,

```
function mod_redirect_subscriber_delete($user_id) {
  $user  = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
  $role   = $user->roles[0];
  if ($role == 'subscriber') {
    add_action("deleted_user", function(){
        wp_redirect( admin_url('/index.php') );
        exit;
    });
  }
}
add_action("delete_user", "mod_redirect_subscriber_delete");
```

Anonymous functions (closures), available in PHP 5.3+.

Benefits:

- No need to remove the initial hook on `delete_user`
- No need to re-run `wp_delete_user()`
- You still get to hook onto `deleted_user` because we retain the user's role within the function, hence we place our closure in the `if(conditional)` statement.

Answer (score 2):

### a) `delete_user` hook:

Here is one idea:

Add this into your code to delete the user:

```
remove_action("delete_user", "mod_redirect_subscriber_delete");
wp_delete_user($user_id);
```

where we remove the action callback to prevent it calling it self again.

So your code becomes:

```
function mod_redirect_subscriber_delete($user_id) {
  $user  = get_user_by('id', $user_id);
  $role   = $user->roles[0];
  if ($role == 'subscriber') {

    // start extra:
    remove_action("delete_user", "mod_redirect_subscriber_delete");
    wp_delete_user($user_id);
    // end extra

    wp_redirect( admin_url('/index.php') );
    exit;
  }
}
add_action("delete_user", "mod_redirect_subscriber_delete");
```

### b) `deleted_user` hook:

The `deleted_user` hook is activated *after* the user has been deleted, but not *before* as in the `delete_user` case.

That means you can't check the role of the user, since it has been deleted.

You could use it like this, but for all users:

```
function mod_redirect_subscriber_deleted($user_id) {
   wp_redirect( admin_url('/index.php') );
   exit();
}
add_action("deleted_user", "mod_redirect_subscriber_deleted");
```